# Too many redirects - Python

Tags: python, ssh

I have two python files in a directory on my server one like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python


print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "hi"
```

and one like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python


print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "worked"
```

but when I go to the first script I get an error like this while the second one works?

[image]

And when I try to run it from my ssh I get no file or directory but I know its there, and i have triple checked I am typing in the other command, and when I run the 2nd scrip from ssh it works.

Why is this happening, there no differce?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a web server configuration issue, not Python issue.

Comment: How are you running your Python scripts?